# Installing eclipse for ruby on rails

Tags: eclipse, ide

i have the fallowing problem with my installing(easy eclipse), but ran the progam annd i got an error to check in c\user\workspace\metadata\log for the error and i got this:

```
!SESSION 2012-07-10 18:52:27.835 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20070212-1330
java.version=1.5.0_09
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.776
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3236 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(IDEApplication.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.809
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.809
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.aptana.ide.editor.erb_0.2.8.200707021211.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.809
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.lexer_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.809
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.809
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editors_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.810
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.parsing_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.810
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editor.html_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.810
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.812
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.aptana.ide.editor.erb_0.2.8.200707021211.jar [5] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editors_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.lexer_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.parsing_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editor.html_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_1.0.0.v20060603.jar [29] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.813
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.core.filesystem; bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.814
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx_1.0.0.v20060603.jar [30] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.814
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.os=macosx) (|(osgi.arch=x86) (osgi.arch=ppc)))
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.core.filesystem; bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx_3.1.100.v20060605.jar [91] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (osgi.os=macosx)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx_3.2.2.v3236.jar [115] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=carbon) (osgi.os=macosx) (|(osgi.arch=x86)(osgi.arch=ppc)) )
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.2.2.v3236.jar [116] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.815
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.816
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ui.carbon_3.2.0.I20060605-1400.jar [128] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.carbon 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.816
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (osgi.ws=carbon)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.carbon 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.816
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.816
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.update.core.linux_3.2.0.v20060605.jar [148] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.update.core.linux 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.817
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (osgi.os=linux)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.update.core.linux 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:32.817
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.update.core; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
!SESSION 2012-07-10 18:52:46.729 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20070212-1330
java.version=1.5.0_09
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.465
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3236 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(IDEApplication.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.605
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.605
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.aptana.ide.editor.erb_0.2.8.200707021211.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.605
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.parsing_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.606
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.606
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editors_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.606
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editor.html_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.606
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.lexer_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.606
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core.ui_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.609
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.610
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.aptana.ide.editor.erb_0.2.8.200707021211.jar [5] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.610
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editors_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.lexer_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.parsing_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.editor.html_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.aptana.ide.editor.erb 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.aptana.ide.core.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_1.0.0.v20060603.jar [29] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx_1.0.0.v20060603.jar [30] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx_3.1.100.v20060605.jar [91] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.611
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx_3.2.2.v3236.jar [115] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.612
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.2.2.v3236.jar [116] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.612
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ui.carbon_3.2.0.I20060605-1400.jar [128] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-07-10 18:52:48.612
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.update.core.linux_3.2.0.v20060605.jar [148] was not resolved.
```

I have win 7 ultimate - 64. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3236 in java.library.path`

I think this portion of the error says it all.  It says the linker for the Makefile or build program that they used is assuming you have a 32 bit windows installed and it is not finding those libraries in your path.  I suggest browsing around for a 64 bit version or seeing if you can modify the paths in their build if you can.

**Note:**
One thing you might want to check is if you have a 64 bit version of eclipse installed because then these might not be compatible.